# custom billing module algorithm/architechture please

Tags: billing, in-app-billing

**Problem background**
I am making a webapp. Users will be able to see their balance within the app at any given moment in time for any custom-set period. So they can print on screen their statement for last 90 days. There they will see the debit (services rendered by us) and credit (funds submitted by user). At the bottom of the table they will see the balance, which is say "-100$" (they owe us) or "+$460" (they have funds for future). But the tricky part is that before the statement there must be the preceding balance at the very start of statement. So that in this example, by the start of the output period they **ALREADY owed us $1000 before**. So at the bottom of the statement I need to sum the preceding balance and the current one for the selected period.

**The challenge / the question**
How do I start making this module? I am interested in an algorithm tips, db architecture etc. In short, what is the general algorithm (or some) to develop such a module?

P.S. my idea already is that I must record the current balance at any balance-related event from the user or the system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is pretty straight forward.

As you mentioned, you need a database table, recording all your bookings. You actually don't need to record the current balance after each transaction, as this can be easily derived from the list of bookings (using the sum aggregate function).

You then select data based on user input, i.e. the time period they entered. To get the balance before that period, you just sum up all bookings up to the starting point (might do this in a separate query or as a sub query). You also might want to look into creating running totals, like described here for Ms SQL: [Running Totals Ms SQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm)